# how to change listen port from default 7001 to something different?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

Can anyone tell me how to change the default listening port of Weblogic 10.3 to something different? I saw some posts on discussion boards which say that change it under ...//config/config.xml. Even I thought so, but surprisingly, there is no mention of word "port" in that file. Here is the file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<domain xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain" xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security" xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml/1.0/xacml.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator/1.0/passwordvalidator.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/domain.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/security.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls/1.0/wls.xsd">
  <name>vistakon</name>
  <domain-version>10.3.5.0</domain-version>
  <security-configuration>
    <name>vistakon</name>
    <realm>
      <sec:authentication-provider xsi:type="wls:default-authenticatorType"></sec:authentication-provider>
      <sec:authentication-provider xsi:type="wls:default-identity-asserterType">
        <sec:active-type>AuthenticatedUser</sec:active-type>
      </sec:authentication-provider>
      <sec:role-mapper xmlns:xac="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml" xsi:type="xac:xacml-role-mapperType"></sec:role-mapper>
      <sec:authorizer xmlns:xac="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml" xsi:type="xac:xacml-authorizerType"></sec:authorizer>
      <sec:adjudicator xsi:type="wls:default-adjudicatorType"></sec:adjudicator>
      <sec:credential-mapper xsi:type="wls:default-credential-mapperType"></sec:credential-mapper>
      <sec:cert-path-provider xsi:type="wls:web-logic-cert-path-providerType"></sec:cert-path-provider>
      <sec:cert-path-builder>WebLogicCertPathProvider</sec:cert-path-builder>
      <sec:name>myrealm</sec:name>
      <sec:password-validator xmlns:pas="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator" xsi:type="pas:system-password-validatorType">
        <sec:name>SystemPasswordValidator</sec:name>
        <pas:min-password-length>8</pas:min-password-length>
        <pas:min-numeric-or-special-characters>1</pas:min-numeric-or-special-characters>
      </sec:password-validator>
    </realm>
    <default-realm>myrealm</default-realm>
    <credential-encrypted>{AES}1NMyZAwXiucj9+d8cj/LGFmw+yhHyIj/YprGOq/PA9Vg0Se2+DkV54N5AwFzW+fN2SWvU5YtojWvVSTnifrUdT6uso4fpO6inAa3LQccOQv59VFxdceHOMv2h1dkngxq</credential-encrypted>
    <node-manager-username>weblogic</node-manager-username>
    <node-manager-password-encrypted>{AES}tRw5L/hFc8+4J4w1H8uBj3unE0BC06cdk42CyMLR6Pk=</node-manager-password-encrypted>
  </security-configuration>
  <server>
    <name>AdminServer</name>
    <ssl>
      <name>AdminServer</name>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </ssl>
    <listen-port>8080</listen-port>
    <listen-port-enabled>true</listen-port-enabled>
    <listen-address></listen-address>
    <java-compiler>javac</java-compiler>
    <client-cert-proxy-enabled>false</client-cert-proxy-enabled>
    <server-diagnostic-config>
      <wldf-diagnostic-volume>Low</wldf-diagnostic-volume>
    </server-diagnostic-config>
  </server>
  <embedded-ldap>
    <name>vistakon</name>
    <credential-encrypted>{AES}U6dM6LlDLLUYzefQ3M3NnsqijzWKSOgqLqNdJHVJEmeIU5v0wRZGm3ffumXif/uX</credential-encrypted>
  </embedded-ldap>
  <configuration-version>10.3.5.0</configuration-version>
  <app-deployment>
    <name>tbl</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <module-type>war</module-type>
    <source-path>C:\Documents and Settings\bchitte\Desktop\tbl.war</source-path>
    <security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
  </app-deployment>
  <app-deployment>
    <name>DatabaseLoggerService</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <module-type>war</module-type>
    <source-path>C:\Documents and Settings\bchitte\workspace\DatabaseLoggerService\DatabaseLoggerService.war</source-path>
    <security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
  </app-deployment>
  <app-deployment>
    <name>ReadingsProgressLogService</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <module-type>war</module-type>
    <source-path>C:\Documents and Settings\bchitte\workspace\ReadingsProgressLogService\ReadingsProgressLogService.war</source-path>
    <security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
  </app-deployment>
  <app-deployment>
    <name>de</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <module-type>war</module-type>
    <source-path>C:\Documents and Settings\bchitte\workspace\de.vogella.jersey.first\de.vogella.jersey.first.war</source-path>
    <security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
  </app-deployment>
  <app-deployment>
    <name>UpdateWIPQService</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <module-type>war</module-type>
    <source-path>C:\Documents and Settings\bchitte\workspace\UpdateWIPQService\UpdateWIPQService.war</source-path>
    <security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
  </app-deployment>
  <jms-server>
    <name>VistakonJMSServer</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <persistent-store>VistakonFileStore</persistent-store>
  </jms-server>
  <file-store>
    <name>VistakonFileStore</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
  </file-store>
  <jms-system-resource>
    <name>VistakonModule</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <sub-deployment>
      <name>sdVistakon</name>
      <target>VistakonJMSServer</target>
    </sub-deployment>
    <descriptor-file-name>jms/VistakonModule-jms.xml</descriptor-file-name>
  </jms-system-resource>
  <admin-server-name>AdminServer</admin-server-name>
  <jdbc-system-resource>
    <name>jdbc/MSSQL1</name>
    <target></target>
    <descriptor-file-name>jdbc/jdbc2fMSSQL1-5853-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
  </jdbc-system-resource>
</domain>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simplest option ...your can change it from AdminConsole.
Login to AdminConsole--->Server-->--->Configuration--->ListenPort (Change it)!

Comment: you then will need to go into your domain bin directory and open stopWebLogic.sh and stopManagedWeblogic.sh . change all instances of your old port ( 7001 ) to the new one you chose in the console.

Comment: @Codrguy: It's been a long time since I did this, but I don't think I did anything like you said above. Plus it is utility provided by Weblogic itself. So updating required files should be done by it, I guess.

Comment: Not when you are not able to start the server because port is already in use :)

Answer (score 6):

if your port is 7001, since it's the default it might not be mentioned in the config.xml. config.xml only reports stuff which differs from the default, for sake of simplicity.

apart from the config.xml, you should look into a number of other places under your domain-home:

```
bin/stopWebLogic.sh
bin/stopManagedWebLogic.sh
bin/startManagedWebLogic.sh
config/fmwconfig/servers/osbts1as/applications/em/META-INF/emoms.properties
config/config.xml
init-info/startscript.xml
init-info/tokenValue.properties

servers/osbts1as/data/nodemanager/osbts1as.url
servers/osbts1as/data/ldap/conf/replicas.prop
servers/osbts1ms1/data/nodemanager/osbts1ms1.url
servers/osbts1ms1/data/nodemanager/startup.properties

servers/osbts1ms2/data/nodemanager/osbts1ms2.url
servers/osbts1ms2/data/nodemanager/startup.properties
startManagedWebLogic_readme.txt
sysman/state/targets.xml
```

And don't forget to update any internal URIs of your deployed code.

See also http://www.javamonamour.org/2013/04/weblogic-change-admin-port-number.html

Especially changing the listen address/port of the admin can be troublesome. If you change only the managed server, it's a lot easier.

The best option is just rebuilding the domain.

Comment: Most of these files get automatically generated anyway. I would only worry about config.xml and the start and stop WebLogic scripts.

Answer (score 3):

The following lines are used to control the listen-port of a server, both are necessary:

```
    <listen-port>7002</listen-port>
    <listen-port-enabled>true</listen-port-enabled>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change the listen port as per your requirement.
This task can be accomplished in two diffrent ways.
By changing config.xml file 
By changing in admin console
Change the listen port in config.xml as per your requirement and bounce the domain.
Admin Console
Login to AdminConsole->Server->Configuration->ListenPort (Change it)
Note:
It is a bad practice to edit config.xml and try to edit in admin console(It's a good practise as well)

Answer (score 1):

As my experience, you can add another domain which listens different port than 7001, and use this domain in to deploy app.

Here's an example:
http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/fmw/wls/10g/r3/installconfig/install_wls/install_wls.htm

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

To update the listen ports for a server:
   1.Click **Lock & Edit** in the Change Center of the webLogic Administration Console
   2.expand **Environment** and select **Server**
   3.click the name of the server and select **Configuration > General**
   4.Find **Listen Port** to change it
   5.click **Save** and start server.

Comment: Can you explain how to change the configuration files? For someone that does not have access to the weblogic console.

Answer (score 0):

That file has a listen-port element - that should be what you need to change, although it is currently set to 8080, not 7001.

Answer (score 0):

If you still get the exception in the server startup after changing listen port, you should try changing Pointbase server port and debug port in setDomainEnv.cmd

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by Changing the port no. in adrs-instances.xml file:

\JDEV_USER_HOME\system11.1.1.3.37.56.60\o.j2ee\adrs-instances.xml